# Stochastic exponential of a true martingale is also a true martingale?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $M=(M_t)_{t\geq 0}$ be a true martingale. Is the stochastic exponential $(\mathcal{E}(M)_t)_{t\geq 0}$ i.e.
\begin{equation}
\frac{d\mathcal{E}(M)_t}{\mathcal{E}(M)_t}=dM_t, \quad \quad \mathcal{E}(M)_0=1
\end{equation}
also a true martingale?

I know that $\mathcal{E}(M)_t$ is a supermartingale as it is bounded below by $0$.

Comment: Not necessarily. You need more. Classical sufficient criteria are the ones of Novikov and Kazamaki.

Comment: Thanks! But I feel like they kind of overkill as they apply to the case when $M_t$ is a local-martingale whereas in my case $M$ is a true martingale.